# How to convert/decode a string?

Tags: java, string

How to convert/decode strings like this one:

```
<PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&quot;Domino&quot; i &quot;Ko&amp;#347;ci&quot; to gry znane na ca&amp;#322;ym &amp;#347;wiecie od setek lat.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; Zdoby&amp;#322;y uznanie i popularno&amp;#347;&amp;#263; poniewa&amp;#380; sa bardzo proste i niezwykle emocjonuj&amp;#261;ce.</PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>
```

to:

```
<PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION><p><strong>"Domino" i "Kości" to gry znane na całym świecie od setek lat.<br /></strong> Zdobyły uznanie i popularność ponieważ sa bardzo proste i niezwykle emocjonujące.</PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an XML parser, e.g. StAX.

```java
String input = "<PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&quot;Domino&quot; i &quot;Ko&amp;#347;ci&quot; to gry znane na ca&amp;#322;ym &amp;#347;wiecie od setek lat.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; Zdoby&amp;#322;y uznanie i popularno&amp;#347;&amp;#263; poniewa&amp;#380; sa bardzo proste i niezwykle emocjonuj&amp;#261;ce.</PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>";

XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(input));
reader.nextTag(); // Positions on <PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>
String text = reader.getElementText();
reader.close();

System.out.println(text);
```

*Output*

```xml
<p><strong>"Domino" i "Ko&#347;ci" to gry znane na ca&#322;ym &#347;wiecie od setek lat.<br /></strong> Zdoby&#322;y uznanie i popularno&#347;&#263; poniewa&#380; sa bardzo proste i niezwykle emocjonuj&#261;ce.
```

If you want the number-encoded Unicode characters replaced by the actual characters, e.g. `&#347;` → `ś`, you can use regex to do that. The following uses Java 11 features:

```xml
text = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d+);").matcher(text)
        .replaceAll(mr -> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1))));
```

*Output*

```xml
<p><strong>"Domino" i "Kości" to gry znane na całym świecie od setek lat.<br /></strong> Zdobyły uznanie i popularność ponieważ sa bardzo proste i niezwykle emocjonujące.
```